# R Shiny source functions into ui.R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When developing a big Shiny app, the ui.R could get really messy even if we correctly indent every line of the code with consistent style.

In R package `shinydashboard`, we could define `menuItems` in the `sidebarMenu` first and then work on the specific `tabItem` by the `tabName`(defined in the `menuItems`) later in the code. This is a really helpful feature for tidying the code.

Here is an example from its official website:

```
## ui.R ##
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
             badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
      h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
      h2("Widgets tab content")
    )
  )
)

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

However in my real work, I tend to design every piece of the web myself so `shinydashboard` is not my choice. How can I do the same thing as the `shinydashboard` could do, like

```
# define the structure first
tabsetPanel(
    tab1,
    tab2
)

# then work on each tab
 tab1 = tabPanel("tab1", ....),
 tab2 = tabPanel("tab2", ....)
```

I tried with the `renderUI` function but it's not working very well (you can't put `uiOutput` directly in `tabsetPanel`). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Best way is to example the shinydashboard code and see how they do it. Better might be just to download a copy and modify it to do it your way. In either case you would learn a lot.

Comment: examine, not example...

Comment: I generally tend to split my code (it tends to become unruly) into multiple files. So you could do something like:

```
tabsetPanel(
   source("file/path/tab1.R", local = TRUE)[1],
   source("file/path/tab2.R", local = TRUE)[1],
)
```

Then in each tabX.R file, define the UI elements there.